# How to get reference to - and position of - an element created by NgFor

Tags: angular

I have a component that uses `NgFor` to build a row of elements...

```
<div *ngFor="let item of list">{{item.text}}</div>
```

I don't know how wide these elements are but later on I need to be able to reference a specific one, get its `left` value and shift the whole lot so that the chosen one lines up with a certain point.

I've done this by adding `id` to each element...

```
<div *ngFor="let item of list" [id]="item.id">{{item.text}}</div>
```

Then I just use the standard `getElementById()`...

```
let el:HTMLElement = document.getElementById(someId);
let pos:number = el.offsetLeft;
```

This works fine but seems like the kind of thing that could probably be done in a more '*Angular2 way*'. So my question is...

Is this approach ok? If not then what is the **best** way to get a reference to elements created by NgFor so that I can get their various positional and stylistic properties.

Cheers

Comment: Why don't you just apply some css class on your element ? Something like `[class.selected]="item === selectedItem"` with CSS `.selected {margin-left:10px;}`. I mean, do you really need to know the offsetLeft of your element ?

Answer (score 4):

In Angular2 for getting a reference to a specific index, you need to add  **let i = index** inside the ngFor.
Now you will get the index number in local variable,

**NgFor provides several exported values that can be aliased to local variables:**

- index will be set to the current loop iteration for each template
  context.
- first will be set to a Boolean value indicating whether the    item
  is the first one in the iteration.
- last will be set to a Boolean    value indicating whether the item is
  the last one in the iteration.
- even will be set to a Boolean value indicating whether this item has 
  an even index.
- odd will be set to a Boolean value indicating whether    this item
  has an odd index.

In your case the div will look like this

```
<div *ngFor="let item of list ; let i = index">{{item.text}}</div>
```

Hope this will help you.

*NgFor supports **trackBy** option. **trackBy** takes a function which has two arguments: index and item. If **trackBy** is given, Angular tracks changes by the return value of the function.*

For more details go through https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html

Comment: ... This is useful and all, but does not appear to be relevant to the actual question, unless I'm missing something? The original question is not about how to get the index in an ngFor, but about how to access the DOM element output for a specific index of the ngFor, which is a very different thing.

Answer (score 1):

I'd prefer to use custom directive which will work for you.

**Demo : https://plnkr.co/edit/XO1GjQTejR8MxoagTZR5?p=preview**
check broswer's console

```
import { Directive,Input,Outpu,ElementRef,Renderer} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector:"[getRef]",
  host:{
    '(click)':"show()"
  }
})
export class GetEleDirective{

  constructor(private el:ElementRef){ }
  show(){
    console.log(this.el.nativeElement);
    console.log(this.el.nativeElement.offsetLeft);   
  }

}
```

Comment: In my situation there is no interaction with the elements. I have `NamesComp` component that displays a list of names say `Alice | Bob | Carol...` that are laid out left to right, each in its own element. Later, a second component selects a name and a third generates and x/y coord. I want to be able to position my `NamesComp` so that the correct child element with the selected name is aligned with the selected X/Y point.

Comment: Its hard to understand what you are saying.